# What's the correct CSS for loading a font for IE9

Tags: 2010, css

I have the following CSS for loading a font which works fine in Chrome but the font doesn't load in IE9:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: Adelle;
   src: url('AdelleBasic_BoldItalic.eot'); /* for IE */
}

@font-face {
   font-family: Adelle;
   src: url('AdelleBasic_BoldItalic.otf') format('opentype'); /* for other browsers */
}
```

When used the CSS and a 'dummy' HTML locally it works great in IE9, but via SP2010 it doesn't.

I put the font files an accessible directory (path not show in demo code, but it's the correct path ;) )

What CSS code are you guys using?

Thanks

Comment: What error did you get for IE in console ?

Answer (score 1):

Problem found. Apparently some fonts are 'protected' and IE gives an error (in the console of the browser). I found a 'webfont' variant of the font (googled on the filename of the font) and now it works!